# jqGrid: Enable paging while converting HTML table to grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, grid, paging, html-table

Been googling all this while on how to convert an html table to something pagable and sortable, and I have stumbled across jqGrid jquery plugin. I've learned so far that we have to call `tableToGrid()` to convert the table (which we pass as a jquery selector string to the method). I've also tried a host of other things, like for e.g:

```
tableToGrid('#GridView1');

$('#GridView1').jqGrid({
    rowNum: 10,
    pager: '#pager',
    rowList: [10,20,30]
});
```

But all these do not provide me with the proper result. Is paging possible when we convert an html table to grid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try with

```
tableToGrid('#GridView1', {
    rowNum: 10,
    pager: '#pager',
    rowList: [10,20,30]
});
```

You can also add more jqGrid options as the second parameter of `tableToGrid`. You can also get **reference** to the `colModel` of the jqGrid after conversion with respect of

```
var cm = myGrid.getGridParam("colModel");
```

and then modify some parameters of the column model.

UPDATED: for example with the following code you can set some column data as `edittype: "select"`.

```
for (var i = 0, l=cm.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    var colModelColumn = cm[i];
    // search for the clolumn with the name colModelColumnName.
    // variables colModelColumnName and selectedOptions are defined
    // in another code fragment above this one
    if (colModelColumn.name === colModelColumnName) {
        jQuery.extend(colModelColumn, { edittype: "select",
                                        editoptions: { value: selectedOptions }});
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you get a reference to `myGrid`?

Comment: @John: `var myGrid=$("#GridView1");` If one uses in the code many time `$('#GridView1')` which need some searching in the DOM of the page I used save the value in a variable and use it everywhere if I need it. By the way one can use `setColProp` method (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#add_on_grid_methods) to do the same what I wrote in my old answer.