# including jquery menu and jqGrid on the page

Tags: jquery, jsp, jqgrid, master-pages

I have a navigation menu which I need to include on all my pages....through jsp I just include the that menu

```
<div id="header"><jsp:include page="../menu_v1.jsp"/></div>
```

but problem is that my menu contains `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` Now when I want to use my jqGrid which is define on my new page inside `<script></script>`it doesn't show up....because its conflicting with my header jquery script...My tried solutions:

1. Using `iframe` but this will not let me control my other pages.
2. Instead of including `<jsp:include page=""/>` i can just include all components with jquery navigation on each page under same scrip...Which is probably not at all a good solution since whenever I need to include more components in my menu than I have to make changes on each pages...

If anyone have better solution ...please let me know ....thanks!

**Update:** My main menu code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[

var navMenu = function(){

    jQuery("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>"); 

    jQuery("ul.topnav li span").hover(function() { 

        jQuery(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); 

        jQuery(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){  
            jQuery(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); 
        });
        }).hover(function() { 
            jQuery(this).addClass("subhover"); 
        }, function(){  
            jQuery(this).removeClass("subhover"); 
    });

}
//]]>
</script>


    <div id="topbar">
         <div class="disclaimer"></div>
        <ul class="topnav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Order Management</a>

                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/1.jsp">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/jsp/2.jsp">2</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">3</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/3.jsp">3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">4</a>
                <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/4.1.do">4.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/4.2.jsp">Add Spog</a></li>
                <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/4.3.jsp">4.3</a></li>

                </ul>
            </li>


        </ul>
    </div>
```

another page using menu:

```
script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    navMenu();        
  jQuery("#test").jqGrid({
                    sortable:true,
                    url: '',
                    datatype:'json',
                 colNames:['col1','col2', 'col3'], 
                 colModel:[  {name:'col1',index:'col1', width:85, sorttype:"int", align:"center", key:true},
                             {name:'col2',index:'col2', width:40, sorttype:"int", align:"center"},
                             {name:'col3',index:'col3', width:100, align:"center"},
                              ],

               rowNum:10,
               rowList:[10,20,30],
               jsonReader : {repeatitems: false,
                    root: function(obj) {
                        return obj;
                    },
                    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
                },
               pager: '#pager',
               sortname: 'col1',
               sortorder: "desc",
               loadonce:true,
               viewrecords: true,
               multiselect: true,
               caption: "Test",
               height:230 
             }); 
          jQuery("#test").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager10',{view:true,add:false,edit:false,del:false, searchtext:'Filter'},{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true});
         jQuery("#test").jqGrid('hideCol', 'cb');


  }) ;        
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><jsp:include page="../menu_v1.jsp"/></div>
```

But now problem is that my menu and main jqGrid is not at at all working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have solved the problem :

1) Whenever creating any navigation menu :(Bozho's suggestion)
   Link CSS files attached to that nav menu .
   Don't use any `<html>,<head>,<title> and <body>` tags.
   just use , (for CSS) and  (which will contain the nav menu).

2) Use `<jsp:include page="../navMenu.jsp"/>` inside the `<div id="header"><jsp:include page="../navMenu.jsp"/></div>`
and make necessary adjustment in your CSS .

3) All js files keep it inside one file using different function , like:

```
var navBar = function(){}
  var otherScript = function(){}
```

so when you want to use those files just use :
  in case of jQuery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                          navMenu();
                          otherScript();
                     });
```

So that you don't have multiple js files floating around your server.

Please let me know if anyone have any doubts or questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- your menu should not have `<html><head>` etc.
- you can define the scripts it needs in the page that includes it
- if that page is also constructed with includes, above the `<jsp:include` of the header, define a variable (with `<c:set`) to hold all scripts that are needed, and then parse this in the header.

Instead of the above steps, you you can use some templating engine like [tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/), [sitemesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/), [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/), [freemaker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/). The structuring of pages there is different and you'd have to adapt your pages.

Comment: I will be able if you show me your code. Now I can only guess.