# jqGrid setCell function 5th parameter and edit mode

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid where I want all the rows to be in edit mode.  Under certain conditions, however, I want a cell in that row to be readonly based on some condition of the row data, but I can't seem to get the grid to bend to my will (yet).

This is what I currently have.

```
$(grid).addRowData(...);  // omitted for clarity
$(grid).jqGrid('editRow',rowid);
if (someCondition){
     $(grid).setCell(rowid, 'col1', '', '', {editable: false});
}
```

The row is added and put into edit mode just as I want, but when it gets to the call to setCell(), it doesn't seem to affect the cell.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid was already using column formatters for other columns so I decided to go that route.  I couldn't get it to not change the entire column to readonly/editable using the method described by Oleg.  I also decided to store readonly state as part of the grid cell value.

colModel:

```
{ name: 'ARNumber', width: 70, editable: false, sortable: false, formatter: 'optionalReadonlyInputCellFormatter'},
```

setup of my formatter/unformatter:

```
$.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
    optionalReadonlyInputCellFormatter: formatOptionalReadonlyInputCell
});

$.extend($.fn.fmatter.optionalReadonlyInputCellFormatter, {
    unformat: unformatOptionalReadonlyInputCell
});
```

formatter/unformatter functions:

```
function formatOptionalReadonlyInputCell(cellvalue, options, rowdata) {
    var readonly = cellvalue === undefined;
    if (readonly)
        return displayARNumberInput('');

    vals = cellvalue.split(",");
    var cellValue = vals[0];
    var readonly = !(vals[1] === undefined) || vals[1] == 1;

    if (readonly) {
        return displayARNumberSpan(cellValue);
    }
    else {
       return displayARNumberInput(cellValue);
    }
}

function unformatOptionalReadonlyInputCell(cellvalue, options, cellobject) {
    var readonly = (cellvalue == "") ? "0" : "1";
    if (readonly == "1") {
        return cellvalue + "," + readonly;
    }
    else {
        return $(cellobject).children().val() + "," + readonly;
    }
}

function displayARNumberInput(value) {
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    element.type = "text";
    element.value = value;
    return element.outerHTML;
}

function displayARNumberSpan(value) {
    var element = document.createElement("span");
    element.innerText = value;
    return element.outerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to modify the property of the cell **before** you call the `editRow` method.

Moreover I know only `editable` attribute for the row which can be "1" or "0" and class "not-editable-row" also for the class. Does the `editable` attribute for the cell exist?

There is one way which can work. You can modify the `editable` attribute *for the column* in the `colModel` before the call of the `editRow` method and reset this to the original state after the `editRow` call. See [jqGrid: Enable paging while converting HTML table to grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501983/jqgrid-enable-paging-while-converting-html-table-to-grid/3507004#3507004) for an example how to make a dynamic modification in the `colModel`.

**UPDATED**: If you already use custom formatter, you can also include that in your code [custom editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom). An example you will find here [Add multiple input elements in a custom edit type field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054811/add-multiple-input-elements-in-a-custom-edit-type-field/3055626#3055626). Custom formatter will be used only to display the data in the grid, but **custom_element** and **custom_value** if the row is in the editing mode.